# Magento 2.15 after cache flush made .css changes disapeared

Tags: css, cache, magento2.1.5

Any advise how is **the best to adjust .css (colors)**, that it would stay permanently?

After editorials in .css and flushed cached all changes in .css disappeared. Any advise how I could keep them permanently?

Comment: Were you editing css files in `install_root/pub/static`?

Comment: yes, in there. pub/static/frontend/Magento/luma/de_DE/css

Answer (score 1):

Magento2 dont writes CSS directly on css files.

**Magento CSS preprocessing is different totally different process. Its using LESS for Css processing**

In css files, you cannot write css code directly:

> 1. For any changes at css files, ***you should write code in respective
>      less files***

Then:

> 2.Magento2 less processor, is take all less from theme ,then genereta
>   css and less at 
>   `MagentoDir/var/view_preprocessed/source/[Area=frontend/adminhtml]/[Vendorname]/[ThemeName]/en_US/css`

After that:

> 3. copy those css to  `MagentoDir/pub/static/[Area=frontend/adminhtml]
>      /[Vendorname]/[ThemeName]/`

So when you have cache then files at `MagentoDir/var/view_preprocessed` replaced  .

So if  you anything changes at **pub/static** and refresh the  it **automatically remove** from those as those folder files are regenerate whenever run flush cache.

Answer (score 1):

To make your CSS changes stay permanently in Magento 2

Follow below steps for adding custom css and changing existing CSS.

**Option 1)** Extend the module whom CSS you want to change, **for example cart page css**

so after extending **Magento_Checkout** module you can change that in _cart.less under below extended path

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Checkout/web/css/source/module/_cart.less
```

**Option 2)** **Extend  _extend.less** under below path , here you can also **write your custom CSS/LESS** or can overwrite existing.

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/web/css/source/_extend.less
```

**Option 3) Adding Via XML** , for example adding bootstrap CSS/JS or your custom stylesheet

Add below code in your **default_head_blocks.xml** under your extended theme

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/Magento_Theme/layout/default_head_blocks.xml

<css src="css/bootstrap.css" />
<css src="css/custom.css" />
<script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
```

kepp all file under below path to work flawless

```
app/design/frontend/vendorname/themename/web/css/custom.css
```

To make less changes work efficiently don't forget to run **upgrade/deploy/cach**e commands

I hope this will help you out